# Solving a system of Vector Equations involving dot and cross products

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, systems-of-equations, inner-products, cross-product

I have a following  question on vector and would like to verify if my solution is correct or not .

Suppose $\vec{a}$ be non zero and $\vec{b}$ and a scalar $c$ be given, if point P with position vector $\vec{r}$ satisfies the equation

$\vec{a}.\vec{r} = c \ldots (1)$

and $\vec{a} \times \vec{r} = \vec{b} \ldots(2)$, find $\vec{r}$

Now, let $\displaystyle\vec{r_{p}}$ denote the vector component of $\vec{r}$ along $\vec{a}$ and

$\vec{r_{n}}$ denote vector component of $\vec{r}$ perpendicular to $\vec{a}$

So, $\vec{r_{p}}$ = $\dfrac{c\vec{a}}{\vec{a}.\vec{a}}$

$\vec{r_{n}}$ = $\vec{r}$ - $\vec{r_{p}}$,

Now $\vec{r_n}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{a}$ so by equation (2)

$\vec{r_{n}}$ is parallel to $\vec{b}$ , or

$\vec{r_{n}}$ = $\lambda \vec{b}$ , using this I  get

$\vec{r}$ = $\dfrac{c\vec{a}}{\vec{a}.\vec{a}} + \lambda \vec{b}$,

Now using equation (2) gives me $\lambda = \frac{1}{\left|a\right|}$, hence

$\vec{r} = \dfrac{c\vec{a}}{\vec{a}.\vec{a}} + \dfrac{\vec{b}}{\left|a\right|}$

Is my solution correct? Can someone please check??

Thank you!!

Comment: How do you know that $\vec a$ is parallel to $\vec b$?

Comment: $\vec{b}$ is perependicular to $\vec{a}$ so, I thought $\vec{r_n}$ is will be parallel to $\vec{b}$

Comment: $\bf r_n$ is perpendicular to $\bf b$.

Comment: Well, $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ are beth perpendicular to $(0,0,1)$, but they ar enot parallel, are they?!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Yes, you  are right that is definitely a mistake, can you give me a hint  how should I proceed further in this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let$$r_1=\frac{(r.a)a}{\|a\|^2}\quad\text{and}\quad r_2=r-r_1.$$Then $r_1\perp r_2$ and $r=r_1+r_2$. Since you alredy know $r_1$, it remains to find $r_2$. Just take$$r_2=\frac{b\times a}{\|a\|^2}.$$This will work, because then\begin{align}a\times r&=a\times r_2\text{ (since $a$ and $r_1$ are parallel)}\\&=a\times\frac{b\times a}{\|a\|^2}\\&=\frac1{\|a\|^2}a\times(b\times a)\\&=\frac1{\|a\|^2}\bigl((a.a)b-(a.b)a\bigr)\\&=b.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
In an above comment, user ${\tt @sato91}$ said that $\ds{\bbx{\vec{a} \perp \vec{b}}}$. Then, $\ds{\vec{r} \equiv \alpha\vec{a} + \beta\vec{b} + \gamma\vec{a}\times\vec{b}}$ and
\begin{align}
&\left\{\begin{array}{lclcl}
\ds{c} & \ds{=} & \ds{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{r}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\alpha\,a^{2}} 
\\
\ds{\vec{b}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\vec{a}\times\vec{r}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\beta\,\vec{a}\times\vec{b} + \gamma\vec{a}\times\pars{\vec{a}\times\vec{b}} =
\beta\,\vec{a}\times\vec{b} - \gamma\,a^{2}\,\vec{b}} 
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

- The first one $\ds{\implies \bbx{\alpha = {c \over a^{2}}}}$.
- The second one
  $$
  \left\{\begin{array}{l}
  \ds{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{a}\times\vec{b} = \beta\pars{\vec{a}\times\vec{b}}^{2} \implies \bbx{\beta = 0}}
  \\
  \ds{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b} = b^{2} = -\gamma a^{2}b^{2} \implies
  \bbx{\gamma = -\,{1 \over a^{2}}}}
  \\ \mbox{}
  \end{array}\right.
  $$
  $$
  \mbox{Then,}\quad
  \bbx{\vec{r} = {c \over a^{2}}\vec{a} - {1 \over a^{2}}\vec{a}\times\vec{b}} \\
  $$